# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /FinancialAssessment.jsp at line 440

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Following is the exact error.

Type Exception report:

> message An exception occurred processing JSP page /FinancialAssessment.jsp at line 440

Description:

> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /FinancialAssessment.jsp at line 440

437:                
438:                    
439:                
440:                

    if(std.prev_treatment_start_date.equals("null"))
    441:                {
    442:                    System.out.println("out by krishna------------");

443:
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

root cause:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.FinancialAssessment_jsp._jspService(FinancialAssessment_jsp.java:542)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: try this `std.prev_treatment_start_date == null`

Comment: I have tried this same error is coming.

Comment: share complete jsp if its not big

Comment: check it properly,`null` is without quotes

Comment: Your root cause says null pointer execption ay line 542 of FinancialAssessment_jsp.java file.. please check this line or post the concerned file.

Comment: system.out `std.prev_treatment_start_date` and tell what u get?

Answer (score 0):

If your error line is that one on the `if` statement which is the most prabably, try this:

```
if( std == null || std.prev_treatment_start_date == null ) {
    .....
```

This is because in java you have to test each object to avoid a `NullPointerException` which means that an object is null and cannot have methods or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Either `std` or `std.prev_treatment_start_date` is null. You should use:

```
if (std == null || std.prev_treatment_start_date == null) {
```

The way you wrote it means "std.prev_treatment_start_date is a string and has a value, and this value equals the string `null`".

Comment: @rushangpatel Gald I could help ;) Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/186921).